# c# form display timing

Tags: c#, forms, timing, display

I have a forms program that displays two forms.  Essentially form1 hides form2, rebuilds it's contents by creating a checkerboard, then shows form2. If I go thru it a step at a time, everything displays fine.  I want to run several sequences of hide-rebuild-show with a short pause between each display of form2 so I can verify it is working as expected.  If I put a msgbox after each show I see form2 drawn correctly.  If I put a 2 second pause (loop doing nothing for 2 seconds) after the show I see the outline of the form but an open space where the checkerboard should be.  I think it's some sort of timing issue but don't know how to fix it.  What's the correct way to do a short pause?

```
    private void Do1Bot()
    {  
        SetStart();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numsess; i++)
        {
            NextSess();
            Do1Sess();
            //MessageBox.Show("After do1 sess");  // Checkerboard appears in the middle of the form this way.
            //Wait(2);  // This way I get the form borders but a blank space in place of a checkerboard.
        }
    }

    private void Wait(int secs)
    {
        DateTime Tend = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(secs);
        do { }             
        while (DateTime.Now < Tend);

    }
```

Comment: Your `Wait` method blocks the UI thread so you're always gonna see it "hang" for the duration the ui thread is blocked

Comment: Adding `Application.DoEvents()` to the wait loop will cause the message pump to cycle, allowing Form2 to be shown.

Comment: Application.DoEvents() solved the problem but I don't understand why.  Since the both methods I tried initially should have been invoked after the form was already shown by  Do1Sess().

Comment: **Never do busy waiting inside a loop**. This is a total waste of CPU cycle and it will also drain your battery uselessly. If you want to have a delay, then use a Timer. By the way, since the Timer is already in the toolbox, you don't have any excuse for not using it.

Comment: What I am looking for is understanding.  If Form2 was shown in Do1Sess, why isn't it visible no matter what sort of delay I use?  Of course I know that a do-nothing loop isn't production code, it was a quick and dirty way attempt to see the form after updating.  It showed the outline of the form but not the contents.  Are you saying that the form.show event isn't completed before the next instruction?  I read the stuff about DoEvents and I understand how it would help for simultaneous events but  these are sequential as I understand it.  Please disabuse me of my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Application.DoEvents() to the wait loop (thanks to Sam Axe) solved the problem.